# Creating custom axis labels for a 3D surface graph using plotly

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, surface

I am building a plotly surface that follows their online example [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-surface-plots/).  I haven't been able to find an example of a 3D surface with custom axis labels like they have [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/#set-and-style-axes-title-labels-and-ticks).  I tried putting an xaxis object with a title on the layout object then passing it as the third parameter to the Plotly.newPlot() command, but nothing rendered.

Does anyone know an example of this working or know where I can dig into or if it's even possible?

```
var layout = {
    title: 'Surface Plot',
    xaxis: {
        title: 'This is a test'
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot('someDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: For 3d plots you're going to have the set these parameters (xaxis and zaxis as well): https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene-yaxis-title

Comment: hey @d-roy, I don't think it's working.  I'm setting the title and the titlefont properties for all 3 axes.  Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/27cfgLet/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i can tell, d-roy told you the whole truth in his comment yesterday:

```js
var layout = {
  title: 'Mt Bruno Elevation',
  scene: {
    xaxis: {
      title: 'thisIsATest',
      titlefont: {
         color: 'red',
         family: 'Arial, Open Sans',
         size: 12
      }
    },
...
```

Works for me. See:
https://jsfiddle.net/27cfgLet/3/

Comment: Oh wow, sorry d-roy.  I didn't see the global "scene" object in your link.  Thanks for the clarification user1121361